# What's the Name of this Anti-Pattern?

Tags: dry, anti-patterns

What's the name of the anti-pattern illustrated by this example?

```
if (something()) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

It's a DRY violation but I've seen this specific one so much I'm wondering if it has a name.

Comment: The shorter version is http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ReturnBooleanEvaluations but I'm not sure what the antipattern is called.

Comment: somebody tried to name it (but it's not very memorable): http://newcodeflow.com/blog/2012/10/16/common-antipatterns-in-ruby-and-rails

Comment: We may have to coin this ourselves.

Comment: call it the return something:  `return something();` :) same net effect